# How do I pass a variable from inside a movieclip into another movieclip in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

The title kinda says it all..

I am creating a quiz and I set one quiz block with questions into a movieclip. When the person answers the correct answer I want it to add to a counter and pass that value onto the next movieclip. So movieclip one is added to the stage it does something then adds a counter. Then moves to the next frame and movieclip2 is added to the stage. It does something and add to the same counter variable from movieclip1. And so on and so on until no more movieclips.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a global score-type value that increments or that you want to parse a value from your current MovieClip onto the next? Your question content makes me thing the first thing but the title makes me think the latter.

Comment: I think the first thing. Practically all I am wanting to do is ask 3 questions in movieclip one. If the answer is right I want to increment a counter number. If it is wrong no counter is incremented and we just move to the next scene. When movieclip2 is loaded it checks for the input between 3 new questions and if the answer is right again it increments and moves to the movieclip3 which is my last movieclip.In this scene I will then get the counter total and compare to a constant variable number 3. If you get all 3 you get a 100% if you get 2 of 3 you get a 66% and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a quick and easy class like this:

```
package
{
    public class Scoreboard
    {
        // Constants
        public static const TOTAL_QUESTIONS:int = 3;

        // Score value
        public static var correct:int = 0;

        /**
         * Returns success rate as a percentage in decimal form
         */
        public static function get successRate():Number
        {
            return correct / TOTAL_QUESTIONS;
        }
    }
}
```

Where you can change the `TOTAL_QUESTIONS` as you like, and do the following:

```
Scoreboard.correct += 1; // Adds a correct answer
Scoreboard.correct = 0; // Reset the quiz

trace(Scoreboard.successRate); // Output the success rate based on correct answers at the end.
```